# Share a copy of my sheet and make the hyperlink available

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a big spreadsheet and there are a lot of sheets inside. There is a 'summary' sheet that I want to share/publish. This sheet is connected to other sheets via google formula. This sheet collects most of the data from other sheets.

The 'summary' sheet contains 4 columns :

> no, thumbnail, id, notes

'thumbnail' column is a special column that contains images. The images are stored on other server so they are loaded into the cells using image() function. Also I add hyperlink() to this image so when I hover the image I can see the hyperlink pop up and when I click it , It will direct me to other website. Everything is working fine.

Now , I want to share the data on this sheet to my team but I don't want to share the 'live' sheet (So they won't see any update if I modify any data). I want just to make a 'flattened' copy of it (without any dependency to other sheets).

I tried some methods :

1. download as .pdf
   Usually I download this sheet as .pdf then share it. This is the cleanest method but the problem is that the hyperlink will not be available in the pdf.
2. copy paste to new spreadsheet
   If I paste from my 'summary' sheet to new spreadsheet, it will have dependency problem from my google formula. If I do  'paste-special' , it won't copy the images so I have to copy images separately.
3. using importrange() or using publish menu
   The problem with this method, the sheet will get updated every time I modify the original data.
4. make a copy of the whole spreadsheet then using importrange() to it. The problem is the spreadsheet is very big. If I have to make a copy for every single new data-share then it is not efficient and not fun to manage.

So far method 2 works but need extra step.
Can anyone help if there any better method ?

Thanks

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

From your question, I guessed that method 2 might be close to your goal. When your method 2 is modified, how about the following flow?

1. Copy the target sheet to the same Google Spreadsheet as a temporal sheet.
2. Remove all formulas in the temporal sheet. This is from `I want just to make a 'flattened' copy of it (without any dependency on other sheets).`.
3. Create a new Spreadsheet.
4. Copy the temporal sheet to the created new Spreadsheet.
5. Delete the initial sheet and the temporal sheet.

By this flow, I thought that a new Spreadsheet including the target sheet could be created by removing all formulas.

I thought that in the case of this flow when a script is used, this process can be simply run. So, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of your Google Spreadsheet you want to copy the specific sheet. And, please set the target sheet name.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const targetSheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your target sheet name. This sheet is copied.

  // 1. Copy the target sheet to the same Google Spreadsheet as a temporal sheet.
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(targetSheetName);
  const temp = targetSheet.copyTo(ss);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // This line might not be required to be used.
  const tempRange = temp.getDataRange();

  // 2. Remove all formulas in the temporal sheet.
  tempRange.copyTo(tempRange, { contentsOnly: true });
  SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // This line might not be required to be used.

  // 3. Create a new Spreadsheet.
  const newSs = SpreadsheetApp.create("new spreadsheet");
  const folder = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).getParents().next();
  DriveApp.getFileById(newSs.getId()).moveTo(folder);

  // 4. Copy the temporal sheet to the created new Spreadsheet.
  temp.copyTo(newSs).setName(targetSheetName);

  // 5. Delete the initial sheet and the temporal sheet.
  newSs.deleteSheet(newSs.getSheets()[0]);
  ss.deleteSheet(temp);
}
```

- When the function `myFunction` is run, a new Spreadsheet including the target sheet is created in the same folder of your Google Spreadsheet.
- If you want to share the new Spreadsheet, I think that `newSs.addEditors(["email1", "email2",,,]);` and `newSs.addViewers(["email1", "email2",,,]);` might be able to be used.

#### References:

- [copyTo(spreadsheet) of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copyTo(Spreadsheet))
- [copyTo(destination, options) of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range,Object))